# In the IVP, $x'=\sin(x)$ , x(0)=$\pi$/4 , why must x(t) never equal $\pi$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP:

$x'=\sin(x)$ , x(0)=$\pi$/4

I want to understand why x(t) can never equal $\pi$. Now I understand that this ODE can be solved analytically. But in the resource I am using, i.e. the linked part of the lecture:  https://youtu.be/ycJEoqmQvwg?t=3851 Professor Strogatz manages to show that the asymptotic limit is $\pi$ merely by considering the phase plane. Now I understand that if x(t) is never equal to $\pi$, then since $\sin(x)$ is positive on [$\pi$/4,$\pi$), and since $\sin(\pi)$=0, then the limit at infinity must be $\pi$. But why can we deduce (without consulting the analytic solution), that x(t) never assumes the value $\pi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe $x = \pi$ solves the ode. By existence and uniqueness theorem of ode, we see that the solution with $x(0)= \pi/4$ will never cross the line $x=\pi$.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "uniqueness of ODE"?

Comment: I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Oh, so is it true that two solutions of a first order ODE with different initial conditions must never intersect?

Comment: Basically, there exists at most one trajectory that passes through each point $(t, x)$

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know of an online reference explaining why existence and uniqueness for autonomous first order ODE implies that two solutions to the same ODE cannot intersect? I have been trying to prove it and am unable to even in the case of the original system.

Comment: So I understand that for our equation there is a unique solution with initial condition x(0)=a, but why then cannot x(t) and pi intersect (of course then x(t) would then equal pi for all later time) i.e. x(b)=pi implies x(b+t)=pi for all t.

Comment: Suppose you have two solutions passing through the same point, then if I use that point as my initial point then which one will be my solution?